# Snooping memory access in x86 cpus

Tags: multithreading, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture, mesi

I'm reading about cache control protocol as it is documented in `Intel Manual Vol.3(p11)`. The thing that is unclear is snooping memory access. Here is its description:

> Beginning with the P6 family processors, if a processor detects
>   (through snooping) that another processor is trying to access a memory
>   location that it has modified in its cache, but has not yet written
>   back to system memory, the snooping processor will signal the other
>   processor (by means of the `HITM#` signal) that the cache line is held
>   in modified state and will preform an implicit write-back of the
>   modified data. The implicit write-back is transferred directly to the
>   initial requesting processor and snooped by the memory controller to
>   assure that system memory has been updated. Here, the processor with
>   the valid data may pass the data to the other processors without
>   actually writing it to system memory; however, it is the
>   responsibility of the memory controller to snoop this operation and
>   update memory.

Consider the following cache state (according to MESI):

```
       CPU1    CPU2   CPU3
Line1   M       I      -
```

`CPU2` writes to `Line1`.

This is how I see snooping:

1. `CPU2` performs write to a memory that is cached in `Line1`.
2. `CPU1` snoops around and finds the write performed by `CPU2`.
3. `CPU1` signals other `CPU`s with `HITM#` that the `Line1` is in modified state
4. `CPU1` performs write-back of `Line1` data **OR**
   since `CPU1` has valid data at the moment the data will be transffered to both `CPU2` and `CPU3` transferring the `Line1` into Shared (S) state.
5. `CPU2` performs the actual write transferring the `Line1` in its cache in the Modified (M) state and `Line1` in `CPU1` and `CPU3` in the Invalid (I) state.

So by snooping memory access system bus access can be avoided maintaining cache coherency even in case if some CPU writes into a memory location that is in an cached in `Invalid` line. Is that basically what they meant by snooping?

Comment: Snooping isn't a great description for modern CPUs with an integrated memory controller.  Especially Intel since Nehalem with a shared *inclusive* L3 cache that acts as a snoop filter.  It checks cache before trying to write to memory, and that L3 check includes detecting if the line is owned by another core.  So actually a core sense an RFO request if it wants to write a line but doesn't have it in E or M state (and thus *can't* commit data to that cache line).  Or it broadcasts an invalidate before it can do a no-RFO store.

Comment: @PeterCordes From the description of WB memory type: _Write-back operations are triggered when cache lines need to be deallocated, such as when new cache lines are being allocated in a cache that is already full. They also are triggered by the mechanisms used to maintain cache consistency._ The cache line deallocation is clear. But the second is not clear. As you said it is possible to broadcast an invalidate when performing no-RFO storage so no WB-ops are triggered. How can we know the system bus is going to be accessed? Is it controlled by the memory controller?

Comment: In most modern implementations there isn't "a system bus" that multiple cores all snoop the way that MESI description imagines.  At this point, that ancient model is less than helpful because it's so far removed from how anything actually works.  There is snooping between sockets in modern Xeon systems, but that works by sending *snoop requests*, i.e. "check your caches for this, please" and waiting for a response back before storing to local DRAM.

Comment: @PeterCordes Is it documented somewhere for some microarchitecture? Intel Manual Vol.3 provides very few blurred details about it.

Comment: The SDM tells you the programming model, not the implementation!  There are some microarchitecture details are in Intel's optimization manual, and in things like Agner Fog's microarch guide.  Some details on cross-socket snooping are published by Intel because later Xeon models (like Broadwell) have several configurable snoop modes.  Shared inclusive L3 cache as a coherency backstop (instead of write-back all the way to DRAM for another core to read) is somewhat well known.  It was new in NHM, and Kanter's Nehalem writeup discusses it: https://www.realworldtech.com/nehalem/7/

Comment: I believe snooping once was literally "sniffing" the bus to be informed when a coherent agent (i.e. able to access the caches) requested a cache line. Today only the "being informed" part remains with agents actively exchanging messages to keep themselves coherent. If you search "intel snoop" on Google Patents you'll find a lot of interesting results. [This one](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7543115?oq=intel+snoop) should shed some light. The language used in the patents is voluntarily abstract and general but you quickly get used to it.